# Handling credentials for different cookbooks and environments

Tags: chef-infra

I've got a development environment based on Vagrant and staging/production on EC2.
Provisioning is done with chef.
I'm thinking about the best way to organise my credentials for the different environments.

For example I've got a cookbook **database** and **application**.
I've got attributes which I can easily put in my environment *.json files because they apply to all cookbooks. **git_server** for example.
But then I've got attributes like **redis_host** which differ from cookbook to cookbook.
My application for example should use **app.redis.intern** and the database machines should use **db.redis.intern**

I could know create attributes like **redis_host_app** and **redis_host_db** to have them still in the environment or I could set them in an attribute file in the specific cookbook. But then I had to check which environment is currently active to decide which values to put in. So every attributes file would have a switch/if block.

I could also go with data bags per environment but this would also end in naming the bags like **redis_host_app**

Which is the recommended way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credentials need to be secured, so I would argue against using node attributes. Instead I would offer one of two alternatives:

1. [Encrypted data bag](https://docs.getchef.com/essentials_data_bags.html#encrypt-a-data-bag-item)
2. [Chef vault](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault)

You can use the node's environment to determine which databag to lookup:

```
bag_item[node.chef_environment]["some_other_key"]
```

Comment: And if you use chef-vault, check out http://techblog.shinymayhem.com/2014/09/bootstrapping-and-secrets-management.html to see one approach to being able to use chef-vault items during provisioning

Answer (score 0):

I think you may receive as many answer as there's people but here's mine:

1 env cookbook with differents attributes files

- `common.rb` for attribute which are common for all environements (lets say default smtp server)
- `envA.rb` with a guard at top like `return if node.chef_environment != 'envA'`
- `envB.rb` with guard too

in envA and envB a `redis_host_app` and a `redis_host_db` attribute.

Like this you can lock in each env the correct version of this cookbook (and easily rollback too).

The drawback is you have to set this cookbook at top of each node runlist (but it could be done at bootstrap time) or makes your cookbooks depend on it

In your app cookbooks an attribute `default['my_app']['redis_host'] = node['redis_host_app']`.

and in db cookbook and attribute `default['my_db']['redis_host'] = 'node['redis_host_db']`

Like this, you may have a wrapper cookbook over your app cookbook wich override the `redis_host` attribute without having to override the env attribute.